# Draw parallelogram on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

There are so many examples to draw rectangles with mouse on canvas. For example, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/d9BPz/546/) jsFiddle.  Is it possible to draw parallelogram?

```js
initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas'));



function initDraw(canvas) {
  function setMousePosition(e) {
    var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
    if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
      mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
      mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
    } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
      mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
      mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }
  };

  var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0
  };
  var element = null;

  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    setMousePosition(e);
    if (element !== null) {
      element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
      element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
      element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
      element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
    }
  }

  canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    if (element !== null) {
      element = null;
      canvas.style.cursor = "default";
      console.log("finsihed.");
    } else {
      console.log("begun.");
      mouse.startX = mouse.x;
      mouse.startY = mouse.y;
      element = document.createElement('div');
      element.className = 'rectangle'
      element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
      element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      canvas.appendChild(element)
      canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}

.rectangle {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

I think this question is self explanatory.

Comment: The question is far from self-explanatory. How do you expect the user to draw parallelograms with the mouse? Two clicks, as in your rectangle example, [won't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKuVN.png). Also, that rectangle example doesn't use `<canvas>` at all.